# Assembly: Half word issue

Tags: assembly, mips

I've stored a half word in the memory,and now I need to read it,there's load half word for it,but I'm not allowed to use it.Can anyone give me any hints about how to make that happen? I suppose I'll need srl and lb but I'm not quite sure...

Comment: Yeah. Load it in two halves and shift the high byte into position.

Comment: or load the 2 bytes and shift into position, but that would be slower than load the word and shift/mask

Comment: Thank you very much...It worked just fine :)